# How to prevent duplicate row data for columns with same names but different in uppre/lower case?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Logging S="T006" version="2" >
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="22" ID="Opened" Msg="some text"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="76" ID="Auth"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="60" ID="Up"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Warning" id="22" ID="Opened" Msg="some text"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="96" ID="Locked"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="84" ID="Done"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="57" ID="Idle"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="10" ID="Inspected" Pos="12"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="148" ID="Started"/>
</Logging>
```

To display the data from this file on datagridview. I create the table columns using the name of the xml attribute names: Date, Severity, id, ID.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Severity", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Msg", typeof(string));

XDocument docLog = XDocument.Load(XML_FILEPATH);

foreach (XElement log in docLog.Descendants("Log"))
{

   DateTime date = (DateTime)log.Attribute("Date");
   string severity = (string)log.Attribute("Severity");
   string id = (string)log.Attribute("id");
   string ID = (string)log.Attribute("ID");
   string msg = (string)log.Attribute("Msg");

   dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { date, severity, id, ID, msg });
}
```

But the displayed data shows the rows of "id" column and duplicates the same for "ID" column. so it skips/ignores the real data/value of the "ID" attributes.

[image: the output table]

How can I prevent this duplication and get the values of the "ID" attributes and display them as rows under the column "ID" ?

trying to output the result on table by StreamReader:

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.Filter = @"All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            myLogfile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            dataset.ReadXml(sr);

            var bindingSource = new BindingSource
            {
                DataSource = dataset,
                DataMember = "Log"
            };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

but this also duplicates the values of "id" into "ID"!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested out your code and it seems to working correctly. The only issue that I found with your code is during the parsing of the XML document for DateTime instead of:

```
DateTime date = (DateTime)log.Attribute("DT");
```

Change it to:

```
DateTime date = (DateTime)log.Attribute("Date");
```

I tested this out on a console application. The code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Severity", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Msg", typeof(string));

            XDocument docLog = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

            foreach (XElement log in docLog.Descendants("Log"))
            {

                DateTime date = (DateTime)log.Attribute("Date");
                string severity = (string)log.Attribute("Severity");
                string id = (string)log.Attribute("id");
                string ID = (string)log.Attribute("ID");
                string msg = (string)log.Attribute("Msg");

                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { date, severity, id, ID, msg });
            }
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);

                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output after making this change:

[image]

Please note that output of this code in the above image is during the debugging process. I showed you what Data Table was being returned by running the code. Also please change the FILEPATH according to your environment.

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string date = row["Date"].ToString();
            string severity = row["Severity"].ToString();
            string id = row["id"].ToString();
            string ID = row["ID"].ToString();
            string msg = row["Msg"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. yes in the post I made a syntax error, but can you please post the entire code that you run to get this table? thanks.

Comment: it's strange. in windows form application i don't get this result, I also tried simple StreamReader also duplicates the result of id into ID